# OSError: 118 with esp32

Tags: python, sockets, esp32, micropython

I am currently working on a code in micropython using the esp32, and getting an error messeage that says "OSError:118". if anyone is familiar with the problem I,d be happy to get help. I'm using pycharm and the socket library.

im creating a very basic client-server connection. the server runs on python, the client is the esp32. when I ran the code with two computers it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your network/wifi is not connected.  Make sure you have a successful connection to the device as it is not active.

Comment: i realized that abit after i uploaded the question and i fixed it. thank you very much nonetheless for commenting :)